# Como mover arquivos firemonkey android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Preciso mover um arquivo da pasta do sistema para outra pasta. Tenho um *BD* dentro da pasta do sistema, quero gerar uma backup, para isso quero copiar o *BD.db3* para outra pasta e depois compacta-lo.

Minha dúvida é como mover o arquivo?

Comment: Amigo, sua pergunta ta muito vaga. Onde está sua dificuldade? Em mover o arquivo ou em compacta-lo? Não sabe fazer ou está dando algum erro? *Passe o maior número de informações para que possamos lhe ajudar.*

Comment: Veja se é [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552360/2556111) o que procura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se alguém também estiver com esta dúvida segue o link que me ajudou: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/FileOperations_(Delphi)

```
uses Androidapi.IOUtils

TFile.Copy(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'DADOS1.db3', 
           GetSharedDownloadsDir + PathDelim + 'DADOS1.db3');
```